# Can we extend any flat metric on the torus to a "standard" global flat metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, symmetry

Let $\mathbb{T}^d=\mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d$ be the $d$-dimensional torus. Let $p \in M$, and let $U \subseteq \mathbb{T}^d$ be an open neighbourhood of $p$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $g_U$ be a flat Riemannian metric defined on $U$.

> Can $g_U$ be extended to a smooth metric $h$ on $\mathbb{T}^d$ which is **isometric** to one of the "standard" flat metrics on $\mathbb{T}^d$ induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

In other words, I ask if there exist a metric $h$ on $\mathbb{T}^d$ such that

1. $h$ coincides with $g_U$ on $U$.
2. There exist a global isometry $\phi:(\mathbb{T}^d,h) \to (\mathbb{T}^d,g_0)$ where $g_0$ is **one of the standard metrics**  which come from the identification $\mathbb{T}^d \simeq \mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d$.

The reason I said **"one of"** is that there are multiple possible options for how to identify $\mathbb{T}^d \simeq \mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d$-instead of the standard squares one can use parallelograms with non-straight angles. (I think that different angles will give non-isometric metrics on the Torus).

*I am fine with shrinking $U$ if that's necessary.*

**Edit:**

An easier question is whether or not all flat metrics on the torus are isometric?

Comment: This doesn't work with things like complex structures (when $d=2$), but here there's no problem writing down the metric $\sum dx^i\otimes dx^i$ on $\Bbb R^d$ and observing it's $\Bbb Z^d$-invariant (regardless of how the lattice is chosen) and hence descends to a global metric on $\Bbb T^d$.

Comment: I missed the point of your question, I guess. You could start with a horribly messy, but flat metric on your open subset. As such, it might not be extendable. For example, pick an open square $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ in your torus and take the metric $dx^2/(1-x)^2 + dy^2$. It can't extend (even to the closure). If you are allowed to shrink (as you suggest), then you can extend with a partition of unity, hooking it up to the usual flat metric on the rest of the torus. So I don't know the answer to your question ... :)

Comment: Well, the metric certainly can be extended, as I suggested already, with a partition of unity (probably just two open sets). What is not clear without doing some computation is whether you can insure that the resulting metric will be everywhere flat. (In the example I just gave, the answer is yes, because you do the gluing just in the $x$-coordinate.)

Comment: I haven't gotten any further thinking about this. Of course, you know the standard result that any flat Riemannian manifold is locally isometric to the "usual" $\Bbb R^n$. I don't see how this helps me, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By shrinking $U,$ we can guarantee that $U$ is a smooth $d$-cell (isometrically) embeddable as a bounded region in $\mathbb R^d,$ and thus embeddable in $(\mathbb T^d, \delta)$ where $\delta$ is a large enough standard flat metric on the torus. Letting $\phi : U \to \phi(U)$ denote this isometry, [we can extend](http://doi.org/10.2307/2032968) $\phi$ to a diffeomorphism $\tilde \phi$ of $\mathbb T^d$. The metric $\tilde \phi^* \delta$ is then an extension of $g_U$ that is isometric to the standard metric $\delta.$

As an aside, it is indeed true that any flat metric on a torus is isometric to a standard one: If you have a flat metric $g$ on $\mathbb T^d,$ then this lifts to a flat metric $\tilde g$ on the universal cover, which must thus be isometric to Euclidean $\mathbb R^d.$ The deck transformation group $\pi_1(\mathbb T^d) \simeq \mathbb Z^d$ of this cover acts by $\tilde g$-isometries, so $(\mathbb T^d,g) = (\mathbb R^d,\tilde g)/\mathbb Z^d$ is the quotient of a Euclidean space by an isometric $\mathbb Z^d$-action.

The answer to the "easy question" is that isometry classes of flat metrics on $\mathbb T^d$ are in 1-1 correspondence with isometry classes of lattices in $\mathbb R^d,$ so indeed choosing a differently shaped fundamental domain will give you a non-isometric metric.

Comment: Thank you. I must say I don't really understand why if $U$ is a cell and $g_U$ has finite diameter, then $(U,g_U)$ is isometric to a region $\Omega \subseteq  (\mathbb T^d, \delta)$ where $\delta$ is one of the *standard* metrics (up to a constant scaling I guess). Can you please elaborate on that? This seems to me to be the crucial part of your argument...

Comment: Also, regarding your remark that any flat metric $g$ on a torus is isometric to a standard one: All we know is that the lifted metric $\tilde g$ is flat and $\mathbb{Z}^d$-invariant. It is true that it's isometric to *the* standard metric $\tilde g_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ but this isometry needs not be $\mathbb{Z}^d$-invariant I think. Thus I am not sure that $ (\mathbb T^d,g)$ and $(\mathbb T^d,g_0)$ (where $g_0$ is the metric induced by $\tilde g_0$) would be isometric-since the isometry $(\mathbb{R}^d,\tilde g) \to (\mathbb{R}^d,\tilde g_0)$ cannot necessarily be "projected down" to the torus.

Comment: @Asaf: Hmm, actually, maybe that's not as obvious as I first thought. Any simply connected flat $n$-manifold admits an isometric map to $\mathbb R^n$ (just use a developing/continuation argument using flat coordinates), but on further thought, it's not always true that this map is injective. I don't think my answer works unless you're willing to shrink $U$ enough to make it embeddable as a Euclidean domain.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly, you assume $U$ is small enough, so you will have an isometric embedding $\phi:(U,g|_U) \to (\mathbb{R}^d,g_0)$. And if the image of $\phi$ is "sufficiently small" inside $(\mathbb{R}^d,g_0)$, then you could consider it as a subspace of the standard torus? (so you can now think of $\phi$ as an isometric embedding $(U,g|_U) \to (\mathbb{T}^d,g_0)$?) Sorry for the formality, but I am trying to be careful, since I think it's easy to get confused here.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm saying - so long as the image of $\phi$ is bounded, we can fit it in the interior of a square $\square$ in $\mathbb R^d.$ Identifying opposite edges of $\square$ gives a flat $\mathbb T^d,$ with the natural map $i:\operatorname{int}\square \to \mathbb T^d$ an isometric embedding, so $i\circ \phi$ is an isometric embedding of $U$ in a flat $\mathbb T^d$.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to thank you again for your answer. I am going to use it in a paper, as a minor lemma. Of course, I would like to give you credit. If you have any specific requests (e.g. you want explicit citations) or objections, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @AsafShachar: sure, go ahead - no fuss.